# Drupal 6 CCK: export/import content types

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I've been having a problem with a certain content type. (Any time I try to access a node of that type, I get a `page not found` error.) So I thought I'd export and re-import, to see if that changes anything.

I went to `admin/content/types/export`, and selected the content type in question. Then I deleted that type. Next, I went to `admin/content/types/import`, and pasted the export back in.

I choose `<create>` and hit `import`, and I get the following Drupal messages:

```
[error] An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
[info] An error has occurred adding the content type recruiting_form.
Please check the errors displayed for more details.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the export:

```
$content['type']  = array (
  'name' => 'Recruiting Form',
  'type' => 'recruiting_form',
  'description' => 'Form for prospective fencers',
  'title_label' => 'Legal name',
  'body_label' => '',
  'min_word_count' => '0',
  'help' => 'If you have any questions, contact $RECRUITING$.
<br /> <br />
Once this form is submitted, you will not be able to view or edit it. Use the "preview" button to make sure everything is correct.',
  'input_formats' => 
  array (
    1 => true,
    0 => 1,
    2 => false,
    3 => false,
    4 => false,
    5 => false,
  ),
  'node_options' => 
  array (
    'status' => true,
    'promote' => false,
    'sticky' => false,
    'revision' => false,
  ),
  'language_content_type' => '0',
  'upload' => '1',
  'old_type' => 'recruiting_form',
  'orig_type' => '',
  'module' => 'node',
  'custom' => '1',
  'modified' => '1',
  'locked' => '0',
  'comment' => '0',
  'comment_default_mode' => '4',
  'comment_default_order' => '1',
  'comment_default_per_page' => '50',
  'comment_controls' => '3',
  'comment_anonymous' => '0',
  'comment_subject_field' => '1',
  'comment_preview' => '1',
  'comment_form_location' => '0',
);
$content['groups']  = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Basic Information',
    'group_type' => 'standard',
    'settings' => 
    array (
      'form' => 
      array (
        'style' => 'fieldset_collapsible',
        'description' => '',
      ),
      'display' => 
      array (
        'description' => '',
        'teaser' => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        'full' => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        'token' => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        'label' => 'above',
      ),
    ),
    'weight' => '2',
    'group_name' => 'group_basic_info',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Fencing Information',
    'group_type' => 'standard',
    'settings' => 
    array (
      'form' => 
      array (
        'style' => 'fieldset_collapsible',
        'description' => '',
      ),
      'display' => 
      array (
        'description' => '',
        'teaser' => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        'full' => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        'token' => 
        array (
          'format' => 'fieldset',
          'exclude' => 0,
        ),
        'label' => 'above',
      ),
    ),
    'weight' => '11',
    'group_name' => 'group_fencing_information',
  ),
);
$content['fields']  = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Email',
    'field_name' => 'field_email',
    'type' => 'email',
    'widget_type' => 'email_textfield',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '1',
    'size' => '60',
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'email' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => NULL,
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 1,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'email',
    'widget_module' => 'email',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'email' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Matriculation',
    'field_name' => 'field_matriculation',
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'widget_type' => 'date_text',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '2',
    'default_value' => 'blank',
    'default_value2' => 'same',
    'default_value_code' => '',
    'default_value_code2' => '',
    'input_format' => 'm/d/Y - g:i:sa',
    'input_format_custom' => 'Y',
    'advanced' => 
    array (
      'label_position' => 'above',
      'text_parts' => 
      array (
        'year' => 0,
        'month' => 0,
        'day' => 0,
        'hour' => 0,
        'minute' => 0,
        'second' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'increment' => 1,
    'year_range' => '-3:+3',
    'label_position' => 'above',
    'text_parts' => 
    array (
    ),
    'description' => 'Expected year of matriculation into college',
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 1,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'repeat' => 0,
    'todate' => '',
    'granularity' => 
    array (
      'year' => 'year',
    ),
    'default_format' => 'medium',
    'tz_handling' => 'none',
    'timezone_db' => 'America/New_York',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'date',
    'widget_module' => 'date',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Name of High School',
    'field_name' => 'field_hs_name',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textfield',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '3',
    'rows' => 5,
    'size' => '60',
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_hs_name' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_hs_name][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'GPA',
    'field_name' => 'field_gpa',
    'type' => 'number_float',
    'widget_type' => 'number',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '4',
    'description' => '4.0 scale. If your school doesn\'t have GPA, leave it blank.',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_gpa' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_gpa][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'min' => '0',
    'max' => '4',
    'prefix' => '',
    'suffix' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'number',
    'widget_module' => 'number',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'float',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'SAT',
    'field_name' => 'field_sat',
    'type' => 'number_integer',
    'widget_type' => 'number',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '5',
    'description' => 'Cumulative SAT score',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_sat' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_sat][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'min' => '0',
    'max' => '2400',
    'prefix' => '',
    'suffix' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'number',
    'widget_module' => 'number',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'ACT',
    'field_name' => 'field_act',
    'type' => 'number_integer',
    'widget_type' => 'number',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '6',
    'description' => 'Cumulative ACT score',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_act' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_act][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'min' => '0',
    'max' => '36',
    'prefix' => '',
    'suffix' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'number',
    'widget_module' => 'number',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'College(s)',
    'field_name' => 'field_colleges',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'optionwidgets_select',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '7',
    'description' => 'colleges to which you are applying (2 at most)',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'value' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_colleges' => 
      array (
        'value' => 
        array (
          0 => NULL,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '2',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => 'Arts and Sciences
Industrial Labor Relations
Hotel Administration
Human Ecology
Agriculture and Life Sciences
Engineering
Art, Architecture, and Planning',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'optionwidgets',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Intended Major',
    'field_name' => 'field_intended_major',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textfield',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '8',
    'rows' => 5,
    'size' => '60',
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_intended_major' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_intended_major][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_basic_info',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Weapons',
    'field_name' => 'field_weapons',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'optionwidgets_select',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '12',
    'description' => 'Which weapons do you fence?',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_weapons' => 
      array (
        'value' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '3',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => 'Saber
Foil
Epee
',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'optionwidgets',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'USFA Rating',
    'field_name' => 'field_rating',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textfield',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '13',
    'rows' => 5,
    'size' => '60',
    'description' => 'If you have ratings in multiple weapons, please list them all.',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_rating' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_rating][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Significant Competitive Results',
    'field_name' => 'field_significant_results',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textarea',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '14',
    'rows' => '10',
    'size' => 60,
    'description' => '(JOs, NACs, etc)

Please include how many competitors there were in the event, what it was rated, and the date.

Example: 3rd/222 in Div2 Men\'s Foil, Summer Nationals 2007 ',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_significant_results' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_significant_results][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Years of Experience',
    'field_name' => 'field_years_of_experience',
    'type' => 'number_float',
    'widget_type' => 'number',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '15',
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'fie
```

Comment: I wanted to try your posted export in a local test installation, but it is truncated.

Comment: I posted the rest of it in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rest of the export:

```
array (
    'label' => 'Years of Experience',
    'field_name' => 'field_years_of_experience',
    'type' => 'number_float',
    'widget_type' => 'number',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '15',
    'description' => '',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_years_of_experience' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_years_of_experience][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 1,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'min' => '0',
    'max' => '30',
    'prefix' => '',
    'suffix' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'number',
    'widget_module' => 'number',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'float',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Club',
    'field_name' => 'field_club',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textfield',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '16',
    'rows' => 5,
    'size' => '60',
    'description' => 'Name of club(s) at which you train, currently or in the past',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_club' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_club][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '1',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Coach',
    'field_name' => 'field_coach',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textfield',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '17',
    'rows' => 5,
    'size' => '60',
    'description' => 'Coach(es) with whom you have worked (currently or in the past)',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_coach' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_coach][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '1',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'Other Fencing Accomplishments',
    'field_name' => 'field_other_accomplishments',
    'type' => 'text',
    'widget_type' => 'text_textarea',
    'change' => 'Change basic information',
    'weight' => '18',
    'rows' => '10',
    'size' => 60,
    'description' => '(Captain of team, other awards won, etc) ',
    'default_value' => 
    array (
    ),
    'default_value_php' => '',
    'default_value_widget' => 
    array (
      'field_other_accomplishments' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '',
          '_error_element' => 'default_value_widget][field_other_accomplishments][0][value',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => 'group_fencing_information',
    'required' => 0,
    'multiple' => '0',
    'text_processing' => '0',
    'max_length' => '',
    'allowed_values' => '',
    'allowed_values_php' => '',
    'op' => 'Save field settings',
    'module' => 'text',
    'widget_module' => 'text',
    'columns' => 
    array (
      'value' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => false,
        'sortable' => true,
        'views' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'display_settings' => 
    array (
      'label' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'above',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'teaser' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'full' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
      'token' => 
      array (
        'format' => 'default',
        'exclude' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
$content['extra']  = array (
  'title' => '-5',
  'menu' => '-4',
  'attachments' => '-3',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after combining the two fragments (why did you split it? Is there a size limit to posts here?) and installing two missing CCK modules, I was able to import the content type into my local test instance just fine. Creating a node from it worked, as well as viewing it afterwards.

In short - can't reproduce :/

So something else must be wrong with your Drupal instance to cause this. I have no idea what this might be, but I'd start trying to import another (simpler) content type to see if your import functionality is generally broken or just for this specific import.

If the error occurs just for this import, my next try would be ignoring the import problem and trying to debug the 404 for recruiting_form content, as this could well be related and might be easier to debug. You could start by putting a

> $trace = [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php);

into the [`drupal_not_found()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_not_found/6) function - either `var_dump()` its output or look at it using a debugger. The trace should point you to the function issuing the 404.

If you want to tackle the import problem, I'd start searching for the 'illegal choice' error message in your codebase (normally comes from general form validation) and check the state of things there - using a debugger and/or the trace statements, you might be able to pinpoint the cause for that error, which might give a hint on whats wrong.

Good Luck!

Comment: yeah, originally I posted the entire thing, but SO truncated it, so I posted the rest in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Believe the issue how the node type creation process is conducted with contrib modules.

**The workaround is...**

1. Create a new content type (just the name will do.)
2. Run your import (with the proper machine name) over the top of this stub content type.

Certainly worked for me with a big monster node type.